# How to upload existing mongodb users into Meteor app?

Tags: meteor

We have an existing mongodb which I imported into my Meteor app using:

mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor dump/*mymongodb*

Now it seems I can access any collection just find by using the collection name for example:

```
Meteor.publish 'works', ->
  Works.find({}, {limit: 10, sort: {createdAt: -1}})
```

Seems to work, as we had a collection named works. I didn't even have to define it:

```
@Works = new Meteor.collection('works')
```

although it probably wouldn't hurt to define it.

But I am lost when it comes to the Meteor.users collection. We had a collection in our database called users, but I cannot access that one. How can I get our users collection from other mongodb into Meteor.users for the app?

PS. I can access the users collection directly from terminal using 'meteor mongo' and search db.users.findOne() but I cannot seem to access it from the code files.

Comment: Are you using any of the accounts packages (e.g. `accounts-password`)?

Comment: no i am not, should i  be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need collections to be defined in order to use them. `Meteor.users` is defined by the accounts packages (e.g. `accounts-password`). If you are not using any of those packages, you will need to define the collection like so:

```
@Users = new Mongo.Collection 'users'
```

or

```
@Meteor.users = new Mongo.Collection 'users'
```

I regularly do this in apps which talk to our database but which don't require any user interaction (db migrations, stats reporting, etc.).

Of course, without the accounts packages installed, you get none of the other user functionality, but that may not matter in your case.

Comment: hmm i get the error Error: A method named '/users/insert' is already defined when I try to define 'Users' or 'Meteor.users' the way you mentioned...

Comment: Those will not be defined in an empty project, so you probably have a package which is pulling in an accounts dependency. It may be helpful to list your packages in the question. BTW, prior to trying my answer, I'm assuming that doing `Meteor.users.find().count()` didn't produce anything useful. Is that true?

Comment: Got it working! You know it seems like Meteor.users did take over the entire users collection. Meteor.users.find().count() reported all the users. So something else was wrong, but I got it working by debugging with your help. Pretty cool it seems to work pretty much out of the box...

Comment: I had a package called mizzao:user-status that was causing the error. Hmm is it strange how Meteor.user() has the entire users collection automatically just by importing my existing mongodb

Comment: The existence of the collection isn't defining `Meteor.users`. If you look at the [package.js](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status/blob/master/package.js) for user-status, you'll see that it depends on `accounts-base` which defines `Meteor.users`. Keep in mind that even if you removed this package, others could do the same thing.

Comment: Actually I just remembered that in the end, I will need to connect to our established mongodb instance in the cloud with meteor. So if I connect with another mongodb on sever startup, would it still work? I need to use the user status package. Basically I am trying to use our current database with current users collection to great a group chat app with meteor.

Comment: It seems like that should work. If it doesn't, then open a separate question.